# Exclude element with specific class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get product name in alert box when either image or link is clicked on product page. But there is also one buy now button available which is also currently giving the popup alert if it is clicked. I want to exclude it using jquery. Here is what I am going

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".item").click(function (event) {
        var href = $('a', this).attr("href");
        var target = $('a', this).attr("target");
        var text = $(this).find('.product-name').text();
        event.preventDefault();
        alert(text);
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.open(href, (!target ? "_self" : target));
        }, 300);
    });
});
</script>

<li class="item">

<a href="product1.php" title="Sample Product Name" class="product-image">
    <span class="sale-item">Sale!</span>
    <div class="cat-mouseover"></div>
    <img src="/images/product1.png" alt="Sample Product Name">
</a>
<h2 class="product-name"><a href="product1.php" title="Sample Product Name">Sample Product Name</a></h2>
<div class="price-box">

    <p class="old-price">
        <span class="price-label">For:</span>
        <span class="price" id="old-price-426">&nbsp;199,-</span>
    </p>

    <p class="special-price">
        <span class="price-label"></span>
        <span class="price" id="product-price-426"> Now&nbsp;139,- </span>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="actions">
    <button type="button" title="Buy Now" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy52aXRhLm5vLw,,/product/426/')"><span><span>Buy</span></span>
    </button>
</div>
</li>

<li class="item">

<a href="product1.php" title="Sample Product Name" class="product-image">
    <span class="sale-item">Sale!</span>
    <div class="cat-mouseover"></div>
    <img src="/images/product1.png" alt="Sample Product Name">
</a>
<h2 class="product-name"><a href="product1.php" title="Sample Product Name">Sample Product Name</a></h2>
<div class="price-box">

    <p class="old-price">
        <span class="price-label">For:</span>
        <span class="price" id="old-price-426"> &nbsp;199,- </span>
    </p>

    <p class="special-price">
        <span class="price-label"></span>
        <span class="price" id="product-price-426"> Now&nbsp;139,- </span>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="actions">
    <button type="button" title="Buy Now" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy52aXRhLm5vLw,,/product/426/')"><span><span>Buy</span></span>
    </button>
</div>
</li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/585BC/

Please advise.

Comment: jQuery has a `not` method

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I tried to use not function like this but won't work 
    $(".item").not(".actions").click(function(event) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this at the top of your callback:

```
if ($(event.target).hasClass("btn-cart") || $(event.target).parents(".btn-cart").length !== 0) {
    return;
}
```

Now if the "event.target" (= where the click occured) has the class "btn-cart" or is a child of this "btn-cart", then the execution of your callback returns.

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/585BC/2/

Comment: Your code works fine I can not drop these two spans :(, any other solution in your mind? Highly appreciate your help

Comment: Other than the HTML code, I have complete access to jquery

Comment: Had done the same code, but ddnt know you had already answered, marked mine for deletion

Comment: @Juvian no brother I have marked anything. Can you please help.

Comment: Thanks alot @SebastianG.Marinescu your solution work like a charm. Extremely thankful to you. Can I ask one more question if you can help.

Comment: Of course, but first you should close THIS issue by accepting my answer :) - then you should open a new question for the new problem. You could share the link here in the comments.

Comment: @SebastianG.Marinescu accepted your answer brother :) Posting the new question, will give you the link

Comment: Dear @SebastianG.Marinescu here is the question, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175822/get-product-name-from-parent-element

Answer (score 0):

Just exit the event handler if you click the button:

```
if(($(event.target).is('.button.btn-cart')) return;
// rest of your code goes here
```

Comment: @Johan Nope - he has spans in it, so the event could be originating from the button or the spans

Comment: @SebastianG.Marinescu Ok I didn't read it closesly enough. It would probably be easiest to just use a common class for what he actually wants to trigger the event, rather than making exceptions.

Comment: @Johan Indeed, or just stop bubbling the event in the button-callback (the buttons also have a bound function)