# Get product name from parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I am trying to get the product name in alert box when the "Buy now" button is clicked. Also I need to maintain the onclick event of the button for which I have placed the code in jquery.

```
<h2 class="product-name"><a href="product1.php" title="Sample Product Name">Sample Product Name</a></h2>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LkKbz/

The approach that I did is giving me blank alert box might be because I am calling parent element. Please help

Please note that here I don't want the alert when product name or image is clicked. Just want on button

Comment: The answer provided by juvian will work, and you should look into https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Comment: @SebastianG.Marinescu thanks brother you are really helpful. One issue is that the onClick event is not pushing the URL. Should I remove     window.open(href,(!target?"_self":target)); ? or replace this with something else $('a', this).attr("href");

Comment: Because the url is not on a "href" ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
var text = $(this).parents(".item").find('.product-name').text();
```

Comment: Wow, i first time seeing parents(), i was using parent() multiple times :D Now i'm feel bad.

Comment: Dom traveling it's like Star Trek for Web Dev's :D Thx for this link.

Comment: @NikolayTalanov: I am happy I wasn't the only one. parents() whoop whoop

Comment: @juvian thanks man your solution worked fine. But one issue, the onClick event that is on the button is not pushing the URL, any advise regarding this ?

Comment: @user3550203 is setLocation a function you made? You want to redirect user to that url after the alert?

Comment: @juvian yes exactly, after the alert user should be taken to the URL that is under onClick="setLocation('')"

Comment: @user3550203 You would need to do something like this then: http://jsfiddle.net/juvian/LkKbz/4/ , instead of onlick just put the link on the href and change url from the onclick event you add

Answer (score 0):

here is answer

```
var text = $(this).parents('li').first().find('.product-name').text();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LkKbz/1/